# Not able to use multiple animations - TailwindCSS

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Currently am creating my first website.

I have added two custom animations within my tailwind.config.css, but only am able to use one of them.

```
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      animation: {
        wiggle: 'wiggle 1s ease-in-out infinite',
      },
      animation: {
        text: 'text 5s ease infinite',
      },
      keyframes: {
        wiggle: {
          '0%, 100%': { transform: 'rotate(-3deg)' },
          '50%': { transform: 'rotate(3deg)' },
        }
      },
      keyframes: {
        text: {
          '0%, 100%': {
            'background-size': '200% 200%',
            'background-position': 'left center'
          },
          '50%': {
            'background-size': '200% 200%',
            'background-position': 'right center'
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my tailwind.config.css

I am able to use the animate-text, but not animate-wiggle.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The way you define the animations and keyframes isn't valid JSON, instead of

```
animation: {
  wiggle: 'wiggle 1s ease-in-out infinite',
},
animation: {
  text: 'text 5s ease infinite',
},
```

you should write it as

```
animation: {
  wiggle: 'wiggle 1s ease-in-out infinite',
  text: 'text 5s ease infinite',
},
```

The same holds for the keyframes section.